# How do you compile wxPython under cygwin?

Tags: python, installation, wxpython, cygwin, compilation

I am using CYGWIN as a platform and would like to use wxPython. Is there a way to get the source compiled and working in cygwin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this link to [build wxPython under Cygwin](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/WxPythonCygwin).  To me this is a much better option than installing all the X11 stuff.  I tried it out using wxPython-src-2.8.12.1, and following the instructions to a tee, it worked perfectly.

Comment: broken link 
https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/WxPythonCygwin

Answer (score 3):

You would need a full working X environment to get it to work.  It would be much easier to just use Python and wxPython under plain vanilla Windows.  Do you have a special case?

Comment: Yes I really want to avoid using plain vanilla windows.It is for a front end for a librarian's  build scrip. The librarian really doesn't want to install python and wxpython on her windows. I have thought about win32::gui in perl or even tcl/tck or perl/tk but I thought I would give python a shot.

Comment: The gui environment for Python under Cygwin would be X11.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the whole point of using wxPython being to use WxWidgets? Isn't the whole point of using THAT being to have a cross platform GUI library?

In other words, forget about X11, and just use the native wxPython on windows.

If you want to avoid requiring the user to install wxPython and its dependencies, consider writing an installer. Alternatively, investigate py2exe to "compile" python to an .exe file (plus supporting .zip and .dll files), which is much more ammendable to "installing by merely copying files".

Comment: py2exe hasn't been updated in a few years. with recent versions of python/wxPython, I've found that cx_freeze is better than py2exe.

Comment: I've found that py2exe still works, but thanks for the tip, I will surely check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I tried another solution for using wxPython in cygwin:

1. I installed python27 and wxPython in Windows7
2. Did "echo 'export PATH=/cygdrive/c/Python27/:$PATH'>>~/.bashrc"
3. Restart cygwin

It works. Cheer!

I don't know if any other Path should be added, but my program was executed on Fedora and it works on there.

Comment: That's not really using wxpython in Cygwin, that's using Windows Python from a Cygwin command line.